# How to determine if the Entity Framework is waiting on a connection from the connection pool?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

I’m seeing some intermittent slowdown \ sql timeout errors that I’m having trouble determining the cause.   I’ve pieced together some clues but I need some help figuring out possible next steps.

**The Problem**

We have a table that has 10+ million records that we run an async count from our web application.  The table is written to often.  Occasionally the count takes 2 minutes, sometime it timeouts, and sometimes it returns under a second all from the same generated sql.

I have a theory that the all the connections in the connection pool are busy so it's waiting... but I don't know of a way to prove it.

**Our Setup**

- SQL 2012, Entity Framework 5.0, and the MVC Web API.

**Clues**

- During the slow response times I can run the same sql via sql
  management studio and it returns under a second.
- During the slow response times all other functionality of the site
  performs fine, slowness is confined to this area.
- Problem only occurs on Production database.  I've tried to reproduce it on development without any luck.

**What I've tried so far**

- We had a problem where the count was locking the table and timing
  out. Because the table was locked for such a long time it caused
  havoc with our application.  We changed the scope to  “read
  un-committed” and that seems to have fixed locking problem but not
  the timeout.
- Profiled the queries generated by entity framework

**Details**

Looking at SQL Profiler here are the queries run.

```
-- network protocol: LPC
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted



 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[CampaignSendResults] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[CampaignId] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 =  CAST( [Extent1].[ResultType] AS int))
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='0BACD499-A665-4721-902A-37EAB49A8A8C'


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[CampaignSendResults] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[CampaignId] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 =  CAST( [Extent1].[ResultType] AS int)) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[SendDate] AS datetime2) >= @p__linq__1)
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='0BACD499-A665-4721-902A-37EAB49A8A8C',@p__linq__1='2013-07-23 00:35:12.6930000'
```

Comment: Have you checked the Performance Counter for the connection pool? This will be on the machine which is executing the EF code, not necessarily where the database is housed.

Comment: I'd start with looking at the query plan for either of those, and see whether any of your indexes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be

```
set arithabort off
```

it should be

```
set arithabort on
```