# All process suspended - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figured it out why our reporting tools slow down.

I ran sp_who2 and I've noticed a few connections that have a status of SUSPENDED and high DiskIO. The interesting thing is there is just one process that runnable at that time which is my sp_who2 query.

What happened with this DB? why is all process is suspended?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817177/what-does-a-status-of-suspended-and-high-diskio-means-from-sp-who2 basically they are waiting for disks to do stuff. If you have enough RAM then that is no longer a problem. How much RAM is your SQL Server allocated?

Comment: i use 64 GB ram, and 32 GB is allocated to SQL Server.
is that possible that my process is never proceed because my RAM is out of resource?

Comment: You need to take a look at whether or not memory is indeed spend and/or the SQL Server can access it. it's a quite possible scenario, depending on the size of your database. However, there can be other things wrong as well - so you need to eliminate factors to move on to the next possible cause.